# GRANTS - ORACLE - PLS-00302

Tags: oracle, plsql, package, sql-grant

I have a package that doesn´t compile, showing this error PLS-00302, pointing to a specific table I created.
Well, I have granted this table to public with grant option, to test.

I recompile the package, but yet its not working, with the same issue.

Does anybody have any suggestion?

Thanks!

Comment: Some code and other details might be helpful, including the schema/object names and the full error message. Does the table have the same name as the schema, I wonder? Or you do you have some other object with that name, e.g. a sequence or synonym?

Comment: Hi!
Full error message: PLS-00302: component 'INT_PROCESSO_INTEGRACAO' must be declared

Comment: Can you debug code that you cannot see?  Neither can anyone else.

Comment: I dont have any other object with this name....
I query dba_objects... Its just my table and its  public synonym.

Comment: Sorry.
I have 15 databases. This process is running in all.
Just 1 database is with this error.
And I just can see this error by querying the dba_errors.

Comment: So you need to diagnose what's different about that one database. We can't do that for you. Start with the DBA_TAB_PRIVS views.